# Parsing a log file with optional fields

Tags: regex, perl

I want to read a log file and split it into four scalars.

This is a log file example:

```
[time1] [error1] [who is1] mess is here1
[time2] [error2] mess is here2
```

And id like to get those scalars as output:

```perl
($time, $err, $who, $mess)=('time1', 'error1', 'who is1', 'mess is here1')
($time, $err, $who, $mess)=('time2', 'error2', '', 'mess is here2')
```

How to do it in Perl?

This is my current code, but it is not working:

```perl
while (<MYFILE>) {
    chomp;
    ($time, $err, $who, $mess)=($_ =~/\[([.]*)\] \[([.]*)\] (\[([.]*)\]|[ ])([.]*)/);
    $logi.= "<tr><td>$time</td><td>$err</td><td>$who</td><td>$mess</td></tr>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my ($time, $err, $who, $mess)=($_ =~/\[(.*?)\]\s+\[(.*?)\]\s+(?:\[(.*?)\]|)\s*(.*)/);
$logi.= "<tr><td>$time</td><td>$err</td><td>".($who||"")."</td><td>$mess</td></tr>\n";
```

The idea is to match the third position with either `[block]` or *nothing*. This is what this does:

```
(?:\[(.*?)\]|)
```

`$who` stays undefined if that part doesn't match. The `$who||""` thing in the printout is to prevent warnings about using an undefined value with concatenation in there.

Comment: Perl student here: If the `m//` matches to `$_` by default, why do you need to write `$_ =~ /.../`? Does it makes any difference on the return values? By the way, I could not find an answer in perldoc pages. If someone knows: where the `m//` returned values are described?

Comment: It's not necessary, I just didn't touch that part at all. Those intermediate vars are not necessary either. you could have just `/regex/; $log.="...$1...$2 "...;`

Answer (score 7):

Here's a way of doing it that's a bit more readable taking advantage of [compiled regexes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) and the /x flag to cause whitespace to be ignored.

```
my $block_re = qr{ \[ (.*?) \] }x;    # [some thing]
my $log_re = qr{^
    $block_re \s+ $block_re \s+ (?: $block_re \s+ )?  # two or three blocks
    (.*)                                              # the log message
$}x;

while($line = <$fh>) {
    my @fields = $line =~ $log_re;
    my $message = pop @fields;
    my($time, $err, $who) = @fields;

    print "time: $time, err: $err, who: $who, message: $message\n";
}
```

One of the key things about the block regex is the use of the "non greedy" match operator, `.*?`.  Normally `.*` will match the longest string, which means `m{ \[ .* \] }x` will match all of "[foo] [bar] [baz]", not just "[foo]".  Telling it to be non-greedy by adding the `?` and it will match the shortest which is just "[foo]".

The other modification I made is to treat the last field, not the fourth one, as the message field.  I suspect your format can have as many of those "[foo]" blocks as it wants.

Comment: Hey watch out, if you keep doing things like that, people are going to start writing readable, elegant perl! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I must disagree with the other answers' suggestions to use non-greedy quantifiers (i.e., `.*?`).  Assuming that `]` is not a valid character in your time/error/who fields, you *are not* looking for the shortest possible sequence of any-characters-at-all followed by a `]`.  You are looking for the longest sequence of non-`]` characters, which is properly written as `[^]]*`.  Doing it this way is both more efficient (the regex engine can immediately stop when it sees a `]` rather than potentially doing a lot of backtracking to find alternative matches) and more accurately conveys your intentions to future programmers reading the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my ($time, $err, $who, $mess) =
    ($_ =~/\[([^]]*)\] \[([^]]*)\] (?:\[([^]]*)\] )?(.*)/);
  $who ||= '(unspecified)';
  print "$time - $err - $who - $mess\n";
}

__DATA__
[time1] [error1] [who is1] mess is here1
[time2] [error2] mess is here2
```

Output:

```
time1 - error1 - who is1 - mess is here1
time2 - error2 - (unspecified) - mess is here2
```

Incidentally, the core problem in your initial regex wasn't the greedy matches anyhow...  You were attempting to match `[.]*` which will only match sequences of literal `.` characters; it would have worked fine on the log entry "[...] [..] [......] ..........", but won't match at all for an entry containing characters other than the `[]` delimiters, the spaces separating the fields, and dots for field contents.

Comment: Micro optimization is not important here as the fields will be very, very small... but since you brought it up, using a negated class is slower.  The expanded, readable regex is fastest by a slim, pointless margin.  https://gist.github.com/927168  This is counter-intuitive as most micro optimizations are.  In addition, using `[^]]` doesn't add any clarity, "the longest sequence of non-] characters" is not any clearer than "the shortest sequence until the next ]".  More importantly, it certainly doesn't make the regex any more readable.

Comment: Agreed that the micro-optimization is pointless here; I should have listed that second and explicitly stated that it's not significant here. I'm mildly surprised by your cmpthese results, though; do you know whether performance of the two approaches is comparable in the general case or if that's only true of short, trivial cases such as this?

Comment: Doing some more testing, the gap gets wider as the fields get longer.  With three log lines of almost 2000 characters each `.*?` is twice as fast.  If I had to guess, I'd say it's an application of the principle that the more you let perl do inside perl the faster it will be.  In other words, `.*?` can be specially optimized in C while `[^]]*` cannot.   Also, I doubt backtracking comes into play with no alternations in the regex.

Comment: @Schwern: I was hoping you'd know the general case offhand rather than running more tests (which I could just as well have done myself), so double thanks for being willing to do so! I stand corrected and I guess that means I'll have to give up my crusade to stamp out non-greedy quantifiers. At least I still have plenty of other things to fight for in the quest for better Perl!  (`strict`, `warnings`, three-arg `open`, lexical filehandles...)

Answer (score 1):

First, it's not working because the regex is wrong. You have things like `\[([.]*)\]` that `[.]` is a character class of the literal `.`, which isn't what you are trying to match. Instead, you want `\[(.*?)\]`, as you see in other answers.

But, I tend to think that if there are optional fields, there will eventually be additional optional fields. As such, I'd parse it for an optional number of fields.

The `\G` anchor with the `/g` flag lets you match a string in scalar context and remember where you left off in the match the next time around. The `/c` flag lets the match fail without resetting that match. This way, I can iterate on the string until I run out of `[...]` groups, then simply grab whatever is left over:

```
sub parse_line {
    local $_ = shift;

    my @items;

    LOOP: {
        if( /\G \s* \[ (.*?) \] \s*/gcx ) {
            push @items, $1;
            redo LOOP;
            }
        else {
            push @items, /\G \s* (.+)/gx;
            last LOOP;
            }
        }

    return @items;
    }
```